# Is there anyway to write logs to Windows Nginx console(non-deamon)

Tags: windows, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am working with the Windows Nginx and writing logs to the Nginx logs folder but I also want to write the error_log to the Nginx console.
I could see that we can use the /dev/stdout or /dev/strerr in case of unix but how could i acheive it in case of Windows.

My Nginx.conf

```
 worker_processes  auto;

  events {
      worker_connections  1024;
  }

  daemon off;

  http {
      include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;

      log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"' ;

      access_log  ./logs/access.log  main;

      keepalive_timeout  65;

      server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;

          access_log  ./logs/host.access.log  main;
        
          #access_log con:;  This does not work.    

          location ~ /(.*) {
              proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:20025/webservice/$1;

              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           
          }
      }
  }
```

I tried to use the
access_log con:; but it did not work.

I also got a hint somewhere that writing logs to Nginx console is not supported in windows Nginx, Is that correct ?